# React native :Unable to resolve module Indeed, none of these files exist:

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, components, custom-component

I'm following [this medium article](https://medium.com/@farid12ansari7/floating-title-or-placeholder-text-input-field-react-native-5fb5932669d) to use `FloatingTitleTextInputField` in my react-native project

below is my project structure

[image]

Here is my code for `HomeScreen.js`

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Text, View, TextInput, StyleSheet} from 'react-native';
import FloatingTitleTextInputField from './customComponents/floating_title_text_input_field';



export default class HomeScreen extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      // <View style={{flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center'}}>
      //   <Text>My First React App</Text>
      //   <TextInput style={{height: 40, borderColor: 'gray', borderWidth: 1}} />
      // </View>

      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <Text style={styles.headerText}>Its Amazing</Text>
          <FloatingTitleTextInputField
            attrName="firstName"
            title="First Name"
            value={this.state.firstName}
            updateMasterState={this._updateMasterState}
          />
          <FloatingTitleTextInputField
            attrName="lastName"
            title="Last Name"
            value={this.state.lastName}
            updateMasterState={this._updateMasterState}
          />
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    paddingTop: 65,
    backgroundColor: 'white',
  },
  labelInput: {
    color: '#673AB7',
  },
  formInput: {
    borderBottomWidth: 1.5,
    marginLeft: 20,
    borderColor: '#333',
  },
  input: {
    borderWidth: 0,
  },
});
```

When i try to use `FloatingTitleTextInputField` inside `HomeScreen.js` I'm getting below error

```
    error Unable to resolve module `./floating_title_text_input_field` from `React Native/AwesomeProject/screens/

HomeScreen.js`: The module `./floating_title_text_input_field` could not be found from `/React Native/AwesomeProject/screens/HomeScreen.js`. Indeed, none of these files exist:


  * `/React Native/AwesomeProject/screens/floating_title_text_input_field(.native||.android.js|.native.js|.js|.android.json|.native.json|.json|.android.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.android.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx)`


  * `/React Native/AwesomeProject/screens/floating_title_text_input_field/index(.native||.android.js|.native.js|.js|.android.json|.native.json|.json|.android.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.android.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx)`. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.


Error: Unable to resolve module `./floating_title_text_input_field` from `React Native/AwesomeProject/screens/HomeScreen.js`: The module `./floating_title_text_input_field` could not be found from `/React Native/AwesomeProject/screens/HomeScreen.js`. Indeed, none of these files exist:
```

Can anybody help me to solve this issue

If need more information please do let me know. Thanks in advance. Your efforts will be appreciated.

Comment: try this import  **import FloatingTitleTextInputField from '../customComponents/floating_title_text_input_field';**

Comment: @bk7 thanks for the quick reply let me check

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're referencing it from the `HomeScreen` component which is in the `screens` directory.  Because you're using the local `./` path, it's trying to find it in `screens/customComponents`.  Using `../customComponents/floating_title_text_input_field` should fix it.

Comment: Thanks i have tried using `import FloatingTitleTextInputField from '../customComponents/FloatingTitleTextInputField';` but still getting same error

Comment: Sorry, I had miswritten the file to be camel case.   I've corrected above

Comment: @Goku FWIW, rather than use relative paths I usually reference items from the project root, as in `myprojectname/customComponents/floating_title_text_input_field`.  Best of luck

Comment: Wild I had the same problem in expo. I renamed my file from someCamel to SomeCamel and VS code was fine with imports '../someCamel', even  expo react native web was okay with it but Ios was not. Thanks, I was driving myself nuts b/c I would I have never checked the file name since the others were working fine.

Answer (score 29):

You can clean the cache on your bundler:

```
npm start --clean-cache
```

Comment: My import file path name was correct. And this solution worked for me

Comment: I don't know why but this also works for me, you need to stop the metro builder and then run this command.

Comment: You saved my time. My path and component everything was correct but somehow was getting module not found error.

Answer (score 5):

Even though your mistake was using the wrong path during the `require` statement, I think it might be useful to share how I solved this issue, where file import path wasn't the reason for the error. I encountered this issue after I added some image assets and required them in my components. But I forgot to build the app again. After several attempts, this is the solution that worked for me.

1. Stop your development server.
2. Install the app on your android device or emulator, using `yarn android/ios`.
3. Start the development server using `yarn start`.

Answer (score 1):

For me, it was due to an automatic import that had a capital letter wrong.

```
import {HomeScreen} from './screens/HomeScreen';

import {HomeScreen} from './screens/homeScreen';
```

Answer (score 0):

The **FloatingTitleTextInputField** component seems a named export. So import it like `import { FloatingTitleTextInputField } from 'the source'`.

Or simply default export the **FloatingTitleTextInputField** like `export default class FloatingTitleTextInputField` in the *floating_title_text_input_field.js* file.

Answer (score 0):

I might be a little late to the Party but if someone is still looking for this issue and hasn't found the solution and is using Expo just make sure if the component you're getting the error from has the

```
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';

return (
<View>
...Some Code
<StatusBar style="auto" />
<View>
)
```

in the return statement for some reason removing this import from the return block will break your code !

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was using `ts` files, but VSCode imported the file as `*.js` instead of `*.ts`. I overlooked it. Changing the import from `*.js` to `*.ts` fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED: In my case, I forgot to add the `.js` at the end of the name of my component.

Adding that fixed for me.