# How can i solve this problem? None of these files exist: * ..\src\components\Main.jsx

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native, relative-path

The full error message is:
None of these files exist:

- ..\src\components\Main.jsx(.native|.android.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.android.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx|.android.js|.native.js|.js|.android.jsx|.native.jsx|.jsx|.android.json|.native.json|.json)
- ..\src\components\Main.jsx\index(.native|.android.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.android.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx|.android.js|.native.js|.js|.android.jsx|.native.jsx|.jsx|.android.json|.native.json|.json)

I have the file Main.jsx in ./src/components/Main.jsx but it doesnt detect it

[VS Code explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JbPjp.png)

The react native version is 0.71.3
The react version is 18.2.0
The node version is 18.14.2

I have tried using backwards slash but htat didnt solve the problem.

App.js

```
import React from 'react'
import Main from './src/components/Main.jsx'

export default function App() {
  return <Main />
}
```

Main.jsx

```
import React from 'react'
import { Text, View } from 'react-native'

const Main = () =>{
    return (
        <View>
            <Text>Hola Mundo</Text>
        </View>
    )
}

export default Main
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: try putting _dot slash_ in front of the path `./src`...

Comment: that didnt work

Comment: "didn't work" and "didn't solve the problem" are not very descriptive.  Perhaps you should post the exact text of the error message you got.

Comment: that didn´t solve the problem and sorry this is the first question i ask, i´m still learning how to post correctly

Comment: Have you tried `npm start --clean-cache` as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68620455/1563833)?  Also, it's a little curious to me that your error starts with `..\src`  And maybe just leave off the .jsx extension?

Comment: i just restart the metro bundler server and the problem was solved, thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

If you are a Mac user try to check file name case sensitivity e.g if your file name is main.js and you are importing Main.js. Then it fails to detect files in mac machines sometime. Moreover try to check if pathname is correct and re-run the server after cleaning npm cache.

For cahce clean you can use command:

```
> npm cache clean –force
```